# Does $(a,b)=\text {tr}(ba)$ define an inner product on $ V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Not sure regarding this one. I've been give 2 claims, one that I  solved and this one. This is the question:

a) Let $V=M_{nxn}(\mathbb R)$ and $a,b \in V$. Does $(a,b)=\text {tr}\,(ba)$ define an inner product on $ V$? (I don't know how to approach it even)

b) $V=R^2$ and $u=(x_1,x_2)$, $v=(y_1,y_2)$. $u,v \in V$. Does $(u,v)=x_1+y_1$ define an internal product on  $V$? (this claim is false, since $(u,v)=x_1y_1+x_2y_2$)

My main problem is with a), as I don't know how to approach it because Idon't know how to show the relation between $\text {tr}\, (ba)$ to $(a,b)=\text {tr}\,(ba)$ being an inner product space.

(if I was wrong in b and it can occur, please note that).

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The definition of an inner product can be found here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html. You have to check if the ones you've been given satisfy the four properties in the link above.

Comment: i've read it and went over my notes, but i don't know how to relate the trace to $(a,b)=tr(ba)$ being or not being an inner product

Comment: You just check whether all properties are satisfied? This really is just a matter of using definitions. Nothing hard here.

Comment: Your argument for b) is wrong. The **standard** inner product $(u,v)$ is equal to $x_1y_1+x_2y_2$, but that's not relevant here. The question is about another mapping, and you have to explain if **that** one is an inner product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula in a) defines a **pre**-inner product (i.e., a bilinear form), but there exist nonzero matrices with $(a,a)=0$. On the other hand, $$(a,b)=\text {Tr}\, (b^Ta) $$ **does** define an inner product.

Your argument for b) is not right. In this case the formula doesn't even give you a  bilinear form. For instance, $$((3,0), (1,1))=4\ne7= ((3,0),(1,0))+((3,0), (0,1)). $$Or, even easier, $$((2,0), (1,0))=3\ne 4=2 ((1,0), (1,0)). $$

Comment: what would be a correct argument for b)? as far as i know, to check if a function is an inner product, i should check symmetry,linearity and it being positive$(x,x) \ge 0$

Comment: can you show me the correct argument so i can learn?

Comment: Please see the edit. More than positive, you want to check that $(x,x)=0\implies x=0$. Otherwise, your definition is that of a pre-inner product.